# Running a bash script to change wallpapers via a cron job

Tags: bash, cron

I built a bash script that simply changes my wallpaper, using a directory within my Dropbox folder that contains all of the wallpaper images. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Select & display a random wallpaper from ~/Dropbox/wallpapers

echo "Changing wallpaper..."

# Get number of files (minus 1) in wallpapers
COUNT="$(ls -l ~/Dropbox/wallpapers | grep -v ^d | wc -l )"
ACTUAL_COUNT=$(($COUNT+1))
echo "Wallpaper count: ${ACTUAL_COUNT}"

# Select random number from 0 to COUNT
RAND=$(( ( RANDOM % $COUNT ) ))
RAND_PLUS_ONE=$(($RAND+1))
echo "Selecting wallpaper ${RAND_PLUS_ONE}"

# Get file path of random wallpaper
WALLPAPERS=(~/Dropbox/wallpapers/*)
WP_PATH=${WALLPAPERS[$RAND]}
echo "Wallpaper file path: ${WP_PATH}"

# Set wallpaper
echo "Rendering ${WP_PATH}"
eval "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///${WP_PATH}'"
```

Basically, I'm selecting a random image within a local directory `~/Dropbox/wallpapers` and rendering it using `gsettings`.

I made this script executable and ran it from the console a few times, for good measure. It works. I named this script `wallpaper_changer.sh` and added it to `~/Dropbox/programming/scripts`.

Now, I'm trying to add a cron job that executes the wallpaper changer script every few hours. To test it, I decided to run the script every minute for the time being. So I ran `crontab -e` and added the following:

```
MAILTO="myemail@example.com"
* * * * * /home/<user>/Dropbox/programming/scripts/wallpaper_changer.sh
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I tracked the logs sent to my email, and I get this as the output:

```
Changing wallpaper...
Wallpaper count: 92
Selecting wallpaper 86
Wallpaper file path: /home/<user>/Dropbox/wallpapers/witcher.png
Rendering /home/<user>/Dropbox/wallpapers/witcher.png

(process:29136): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

So my script is being executed, but the wallpaper isn't being changed. I tried to address the `dconf-WARNING` by following the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457016/how-to-change-gsettings-via-remote-shell), but to no avail.

Has anybody encountered this before? Is there something fundamental that I'm doing wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Solution**

Turns out that the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable isn't set properly when running the script within the context of a cron job. I had to implement the solution from [this Ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140305/cron-not-able-to-succesfully-change-background) to properly set the variable. Interestingly, it *is* set properly when I run the command directly from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to interact with an X environment.

Do either:

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /home/<user>/Dropbox/programming/scripts/wallpaper_changer.sh
```

Or:

```
DISPLAY=:0
* * * * * /home/<user>/Dropbox/programming/scripts/wallpaper_changer.sh
```

Adapt the value of DISPLAY if needed.

Comment: Hi @xhienne, thank you for responding. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like that solution worked. The `dconf-WARNING` error message is suppressed, but the wallpaper still doesn't change. 

Are there other possible values that DISPLAY could be set as to make this work?

Comment: It may depend on your authorizations. Your program, as a cron job, is not bound to your X session. One mandatory thing is to declare your DISPLAY (check that it is the same as `echo $DISPLAY`) but another is to have the credential to interfere with your display. It is more difficult from a cron job. I tested my solution though, on Mint 18, but YMMV. If that doesn't work, the easier for you is probably to create a startup script.

Comment: Hmm - well it looks like I'm setting DISPLAY to the proper value. Interestingly enough, when I run the script from the command line, it changes my wallpaper, but when I prepend it with `sudo`, it still spits out the log info above but doesn't change the wallpaper...you may be right in that it has to do with credentials. I'll keep looking into it. Thank you.

Comment: `sudo` won't help, what matters is properly accessing you X display. You may append `>> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1` at the end of your command and examine `/tmp/cron.log` afterwards to see what went wrong.